# Counting consecutive dates, excluding weekends in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on an absence report in which I need to include employees with 6 consecutive absences, while giving a count of how many consecutive absences there were within a given date range, when there were 6 or more. My biggest issue is dealing with weekends. Since this is for a school, employees work Mon - Fri so in order to count 6 consecutive dates, there will always be a weekend that separates dates. I am working with a lot of data that will be updated daily, so I cannot insert dates into a temp table for this task. I have created a temp table that stores all of the dates between a start and end date, excluding weekends:

```
CREATE TABLE #TimeCardDates (
      ClientID          INT
    , EmpUID                BIGINT
    , BetweenDate           DATE
)

    ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 
              @StartDate StartDate
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
              DATEADD(DAY, 1, StartDate)
        FROM cte
        WHERE StartDate < @EndDate
)
INSERT INTO #TimeCardDates (
      ClientID
    , EmpUID
    , BetweenDate
)
    SELECT 
          e.ClientID
        , e.EmpUID
        , c.StartDate
    FROM cte c
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT e.ClientID, e.EmpUID 
        FROM Employee e 
        JOIN #Clients c 
            ON c.ClientID = e.ClientID
    ) e

DELETE d
FROM #TimeCardDates d
    WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, d.BetweenDate) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
```

Here is an example of the data I am working with in another temp table I have made:

```
 **Employee**       **Description**         **DateAbsent**  **NumberOfConsecDaysAbsent**
 Employee1          Unscheduled Absence     2020-01-09
 Employee1          Unscheduled Absence     2020-01-23
 Employee1          Unscheduled Absence     2020-01-29
 Employee1          Unscheduled Absence     2020-02-05
 Employee1          Unscheduled Absence     2020-03-02
 Employee2          Unscheduled Absence     2020-01-06
 Employee2          Unscheduled Absence     2020-01-27
 Employee2          Unscheduled Absence     2020-02-07
 Employee2          Unscheduled Absence     2020-02-13
 Employee2          Unscheduled Absence     2020-02-26
 Employee3          Unscheduled Absence     2020-01-02
 Employee3          Unscheduled Absence     2020-01-03
 Employee3          Unscheduled Absence     2020-01-06
 Employee3          Unscheduled Absence     2020-01-07
 Employee3          Unscheduled Absence     2020-01-08
 Employee3          Unscheduled Absence     2020-01-09
```

Expected Results from the above data:

```
 Employee3          Unscheduled Absence                        6
```

Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Based on the results can you show the expected results

Comment: 6 Business days translates to 8 calendar days, provided there are no other holidays in that period. You can directly use the 8 calendar days as the difference, which will make your calculation a lot simpler.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you said in your question that you already filtered out weekends by putting everyone into a temp table with only working days, correct? If that's the case, you can use `WHERE EXISTS` and use `INTERVAL 6 DAY` to check.

Answer (score 0):

To generates dates between two dates excluding weekends you can do the following

```
declare @startdate date,@enddate date
 set @startdate=cast('2020-02-01' as date)
 set @enddate=cast('2020-03-01' as date)

;with num_dates
   as (select row_number() over(order by name)-1 as rnk
        from master..spt_values
      )
select @startdate   
      ,dateadd(day,rnk,@startdate) as calendar_dates 
      ,rnk
  from num_dates
 where datepart(dw,dateadd(day,rnk,@startdate)) not in (6,7)
   and dateadd(day,rnk,@startdate) <=@enddate
```

Comment: I know this doesnt answer your question, but this can help determine which days are consecutive between two dates that you should consider( a caveat i assume only those many rows as max diff between start and end dates based on the records in master..spt_values)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option, using `lag` to check if the prior day was a consecutive absence.  You can probably combine the steps into fewer CTEs, but I wanted to script it out so it's easy to see how the logic works.

Note: I added some additional testing data for Employee1 to make sure it was working properly for more than 6 non-consecutive absences.

```
create table #test (employee varchar(20), descr varchar(20), dateabsent date)

insert into #test --Create Sample Data
values
('Employee1','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-01-09'),
('Employee1','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-01-23'),
('Employee1','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-01-29'),
('Employee1','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-02-05'),
('Employee1','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-03-02'),
('Employee1','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-03-03'),
('Employee1','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-03-04'),
('Employee1','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-03-07'),
('Employee1','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-03-12'),
('Employee1','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-03-17'),
('Employee2','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-01-06'),
('Employee2','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-01-27'),
('Employee2','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-02-07'),
('Employee2','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-02-13'),
('Employee2','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-02-26'),
('Employee3','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-01-02'),
('Employee3','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-01-03'),
('Employee3','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-01-06'),
('Employee3','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-01-07'),
('Employee3','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-01-08'),
('Employee3','UnscheduledAbsence','2020-01-09')


; with CTE as (select *, datename(dw,dateabsent) as DW --Day of absence
from #test)

, cte2 as (select *
, case when lag(dateabsent) over (partition by employee order by dateabsent) = dateadd(day, -1, dateabsent) --if this absence immediately follows another absence
    or dw = 'Monday' and lag(dateabsent) over (partition by employee order by dateabsent) = dateadd(day, -3, dateabsent)  --or this is the Monday after a Friday absence
    then 1 else 0 end as Consecutive
from CTE)


, cte3 as (select *
    , sum(cte2.Consecutive) over (partition by employee order by dateabsent) + 1 as TotalConsecutiveAbsences --sum consecutive absences, add one for the current row absence
from cte2)

select cte3.employee, cte3.descr, cte3.TotalConsecutiveAbsences
from cte3
where cte3.TotalConsecutiveAbsences >= 6
```

Edited to clean up the logic a bit and add comments.